# Java Switch Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a problem using switch statement when I tried to deal with a special situation.
For example,
I have 3 cases: A, B, C.

- for A, I want to do statement_1 and statement_3.
- for B, I want to do statement_2 and statement_3.
- for C, I want to do nothing

if I use if-else statement, it will look like the following:

```
 if ( not C){
    do statement_3

   if B
      do statement 2
   else if A
      do statement 1

 }
```

If I want to use switch statement to do the same thing, I have some trouble.

```
switch (variable){
case A:  do statement_1
case B: do statement_2
// how to do statement 3 here?  
}
```

I am trying to avoid the duplicated codes. So I am thinking that how to make the codes as simple as I can.

**UPDATE 1：**

1. to make my codes/question more clear, I just want to make my codes
   as simple/clear as I can, that is why I want to use switch statement
   instead of if-else. Also, I heard that switch-statement is usually
   faster than if-else. (I am not 100% sure though).
2. I want to use switch-case because Case A, B, C are enum type. they
   are not variable. Sorry about the confusion.
3. each statements are more than 10 lines of codes. That is why I do not want to do the followings:

   ```
   switch (enum variable) {
   case A:
     statement1
     statement3
    break;
   case B:
     statement2
     statement3
    break;
   ```

   }

Comment: This code won't work, because Java 6 and older expects a value of a primitive type. Java 7 can dealt that with Strings.

Comment: switch is no good - you can't skip over cases, which is what you'd have to do to avoid coding the call to statement_3 twice

Comment: what's wrong with `if`? If a switch is not the right tool, don't use it. Most of the time, it's not the right tool.

Comment: I think the if is fine too...

Comment: Or [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) and get rid of the if / switch

Comment: 3. Extract your ten-line statements into methods.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

i would recommend to define exactly what staments should be executed:

```
switch (variable){
    case A: 
        statement_1();
        statement_3();
        break;
    case B: 
        statement_2();
        statement_3();
        break;
}
```

**for Update-3:**

create methods for those 10 lines:

```
public void statement_1() {
    //your 10 lines of code
}
```

if you're always executing statement_3, except for case C you can go with if/else-blocks as you wrote them.

but in my honest opinion:
define EXACTLY what has to be done in which case if you have a small amount of cases.
it is easier to read for others

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
switch (variable){
  case A:  do statement_1; do statement_3; break;
  case B:  do statement_2; do statement_3; break;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not nest the switch into the if statement? there is no-repeat code this way.

```
if(!C){
    statement_3;
    switch(variable){
    case A:
        statement_1;
        break;
    case B: 
        statement_2;
        break;
}
```

or make use of both the if-statement and the switch?

```
if(!C){
    statement_3;
}
switch(variable){
case A:
    statement_1;
    break;
case B: 
    statement_2;
    break;
```

Comment: but why use a switch with 2 cases and mix it all up? you don't gain performance or anything. it might be confusing for other developers

Comment: Because the question referred to using a switch statement. If it is only 2 or 3 cases, then the if-elseif-else is the way to go. but if there is a grouping of statements that all share the same code, say a couple dozen times but not under one scenario, why repeat the code when you can have it executed before the switch (as long as a certain condition is not met)?

Answer (score 0):

I often find introducing `enum`s adds clarity. Here I imagine each `enum` is an issue which can be resolved through a number of processes:

```
enum Issue {
  A {
    void handleIt () {
      statement_1();
      statement_3();
    }
  },
  B {
    void handleIt () {
      statement_2();
      statement_3();
    }
  },
  C {
    void handleIt () {
      // Do nothing.
    }
  },
  D {
    void handleIt () {
      A.handleIt();
      B.handleIt();
    }
  };

  abstract void handleIt();
}
```

Note here that you get the added benefit of being able to handle certain issues using the solutions of other issues (see my `D` `enum`).

Answer (score 0):

If a case has more than 2-3 statements it's bette(from point of view of readability and clean code) to extract them as separate methods:

```
switch (variable){
    case A: handleCaseA(); break;
    case B: handleCaseB(); break;
    default: handleDefaultCase(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (variable) {
case A:  
do statement_1;
do statement_3;
break;
case B:
do statement_2;
do statement_3;
break;
}
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: Avoid overt self-promotion. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising)

Answer (score 0):

With Java 12 [switch-expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) you can do it nicely as follows:

```
switch (variable) {
        case A -> statement_1();
                  statement_3();
        case B -> statement_2();
                  statement_3();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use "case," use a switch statement first, and make sure you've got an initialized variable in it. Here's an example.

Use an initialized variable: i.e.

```
(String s=sc.nextLine();)

        switch (s) {
        case "Pepperoni":
            System.out.println("Pepperoni? Nice choice. Please wait............Ding! Here's your pepperoni pizza. Enjoy, and thanks for using the Local Pizzeria!");
        case "Cheese":
            System.out.println("Cheese? Okay! Soft cheese it is! Please wait............Ding! Here's your cheese pizza. Enjoy, and thank you for using the Local Pizzeria!");
            break;
        case "Mushrooms":
            System.out.println("Mushrooms? Veggie person, right? OK! Please wait............Ding! Here's your mushroom pizza. Enjoy, and thanks for using the Local Pizzeria!");
            break;
        case "Beef Bits":
            System.out.println("Beef bits? Like meat? Alright! Please wait............Ding! Here's your beef bit pizza. Enjoy, and thank you for using the Local Pizzeria!");

            break;
        case "Spicy Buffalo Chicken":
            System.out.println("Spicy buffalo chicken? Way to spice things up! Please wait............Ding! Here's your spicy buffalo chicken pizza. Enjoy, and thank you for using the Local Pizzeria!");
            break;
        case "Exit":
            System.out.println("See you soon!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here u must use `if statement` in this way because in `switch` there are normally `default` value also.

```
    if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'B') { System.out.println("Statement 3 ");}
```

```
switch (letter) {
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Statement 1 ");
                break;

            case 'B':
                System.out.println("Statement 2 ");
                break;

            case 'C':
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered wrong value");
}
```